# How to change submenu side appear to left instead of right

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

I have wordpress theme that have menu with submenu that open to the right instead of the left (my language need it to open to the left)? see images below.

I understand that this is a css tweak or a small javascript change. can you please assist me to solve this?

Menu to the right: http://corenetos.com/img/menu2.png

Menu to left: http://corenetos.com/img/menu3.png

Comment: can you post the code you are struggling with?

Comment: oopps i forgot: here is the css and the js http://corenetos.com/img/menu.zip

Comment: Use a service like JSFiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/], no-one wants to download a random .zip that could be anything.

Comment: Your ZIP file contains no HTML. How are we supposed to know how you've used the menu? Also, read what @SMacFadyen said.

Comment: got it to work, but i cant post the answer becouse i dont have enough raputation. :(

Comment: thanks guys, but i need more (3 to go).. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is:

put on the **li ul** of the css submenu the following: **margin-left:-300px**

it will appear on the right